# What is causing bounceback “550 Blocked” from Mimecast?

Tags: email-bounces

Reading Mimecast's FAQ: https://community.mimecast.com/s/article/Mimecast-SMTP-5xx-Error-Codes-573763479

Error 550 with reason "Blocked" is not listed in their FAQ.  I have called Mimecast and they are not returning my call.  We have a client who is getting this bounceback when sending emails through a mass email service.  I have verified their SPF record is correct.  They do not have a DKIM record set up.  Their mass email service says to contact Mimecast.  So I am stuck at the moment and hope someone has an answer for this.

```
X-SendGrid-QueueID: 644483390
X-SendGrid-Sender: <bounces+28313-3d0d-hill=####.com@email.bullhornmail.com>
Arrival-Date: 2020-07-21 19-51-57

Final-Recipient: rfc822; ####@####.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822; ####@####.com
Action: failed
Status: 
Diagnostic-Code: 550 spamcop.mimecast.org Blocked - see https://www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml?167.89.63.60. - https://community.mimecast.com/docs/DOC-1369#550 [bZ52-d7nMLmippSyFi6_bA.us116]
```

Comment: I just noticed another URL and it indicates the server may be on a blacklist but will be removed soon.  Could that be causing it?

Comment: The message explcitly states it was blocked for the IP address being on that RBL. Try again once it has been removed. This seems to be a common problem with SendGrid. They don't seem to notice when their IP addresses get blocked, and don't try again from a different address.

Comment: You'd think the ticket with the mass email provider given this information would be able to tell our client that...  But here we are.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see the 1st URL in my post for some reason.  I was really blind.  I'd love to delete this question but I end up getting banned if I do :(

Answer: https://www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml?167.89.63.60